# Updating multiple array elements at once Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to update multiple elements at once in a multidimensional array/object and having errors with .push and other options I have tried.

```
 var FEtypes= {
    textTemplate: {
       type :"Text",
       size : 50,
       required : "no",
       FEadd : '<input>', 
       label : 'Label',
       top : 0, 
       left : 0
    }, 
    textareaTemplate: {
       type : "Textarea",
       cols : 30,
       rows : 5,
       FEadd :'<textarea>' 
    }
 }
```

This works, but trying to do in one line.

```
 FEtypes[1].left = someVariable1;
 FEtypes[1].top = someVariable2;
```

I have been unsuccessful with:

```
 FEtypes[1].push( {left:someVariable1, top:someVariable2} );
```

I keep getting an error that this is not a function or it does nothing.

Comment: I'm not seeing the multidimensional array here.  FETypes looks like an object with two properties, textTemplate and textareaTemplate, each of which is in turn an object.

Comment: You can't use push on a object like that. push is used to add elements to an array. Not overwrite object properties. Whats wrong with your first example?

Comment: Array is not the same as object. `.push` is a function used for arrays (ex. `["this", "is", "an", "array"]`) and not objects.

Comment: Note that even if you had an array (and not a "plain" object) `.push()` would still be the wrong choice because it _adds_ a new element to the end of an array, it doesn't update an existing element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FEtypes` is an object, not an array.  `Push` is only available on arrays.

If you want to store this structure in an array, it would look something like:

```
var FEtypes= [
      {type :"Text", size : 50,  required : "no", FEadd  :'<input>', label : 'Label', top : 0, left : 0}, 
      {type : "Textarea", cols : 30,  rows : 5,FEadd :'<textarea>' }
];
```

Then

```
FEtypes[1].left = someVariable1;
FEtypes[1].top = someVariable2;
```

If you want to modify multiple properties at once, the jQuery [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) function will get you what you want:

```
$.extend(FEtypes[1], {left:someVariable1, top:someVariable2});
```

**But I think your original structure is more suitable.  Just ditch arrays, and do this:**

```
FEtypes.textareaTemplate.left = someVariable1;
FEtypes.textareaTemplate.top = someVariable2;
```

Or, again, with just one line with jQuery:

```
$.extend(FEtypes.textareaTemplate, {left:someVariable1, top:someVariable2});
```

Comment: `Object` instances and non-`Array` instances do not have elements.  They have only properties.  `var o = FEtypes[1]; o.left = someVariable1,
 o.top = someVariable2;` works, of course, but is not recommended.  You could equally use the semicolon instead of the comma; less error-prone.  Why only one line?

Comment: Thank you. This worked but it seems to have wiped out the rest of the items in the array. So instead of updating the items it only has these two elements.

Comment: You should not be using jQuery for this anyway, it is *so* overkill.  If you want to do this so that it works everywhere, you need a function like extend() that iterates with a `for`-`in` loop over the enumerable properties of the object referred by the passed reference.  Only Mozilla.org JavaScript 1.7+ (Firefox 2.0+, Gecko 1.8.1+) also supports [destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#Destructuring_assignment): `var template = FEtypes.textTemplates; [template.left, template.top] = [someVariable1, someVariable2];`

Comment: @PointedEars - I never meant that OP should drop jQuery into his project *just* for this.  I gave him a non-jQuery way to do what he wanted, then I gave him a jQuery shortcut if it was already in his project, though I should have been more specific about that.  And from his comment, it looks like it already *was* in his project

Comment: Using JQuery quite a bit. The project is much more complicated then the sample code I added. I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 2):

`FEtypes` is an object and it has two properties `textTemplate` and `textareaTemplate`.  It is not an array and does not have a property `[1]`.  As such, you can't use `.push()` or `[1]`.

The proper way to access the `.left` and `.top` parameters or the textareaTemplate property is this:

```
FETypes.textareaTemplate.left = someVariable1;
FETypes.textareaTemplate.top = someVariable2;
```

or for `textTemplate`, it would be this:

```
FETypes.textTemplate.left = someVariable1;
FETypes.textTemplate.top = someVariable2;
```

Both the `textareaTemplate` and `textTemplate` properties are objects.  If you wanted to replace the entire object (thus replacing all other properties on the object), you could do this:

```
FETypes.textTemplate = {left: someVariable1, top: someVariable1};
```

But, when doing that, you would be replacing the entire textTemplate property so it would have no other properties besides `left` and `top`.  Any prior properties like `size` or `required` would be wiped out by the new assignment.

If you want to update just the `left` and `top` properties leaving the others in place, you have to assign to them individually - there is no shortcut unless you write a function to do so like this:

```
function updatePosition(obj, leftPos, topPos) {
    obj.left = leftPos;
    obj.top = topPos;
}
```

and then call that function like this:

```
updatePosition(FETypes.textareaTemplate, someVariable1, someVariable2);
```

Answer (score 0):

`FEtypes` does **not** refer to an `Array` instance.  As a result, it has no `1` property, and `undefined`, which is the result of `FEtypes[1]` has no properties at all.  Your code does not, cannot work.  Check the error console.

Answer (score 0):

try this using lodash or underscore:

```
_.chain(FEtypes).map(item => {
      item.left = item.type === "Text" ? someVariable1 : item.left;
      item.top = item.type === "Text" ? someVariable2 : item.top;
      return item;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

in modern javascript

```js
Object.assign(FEtypes[1], {
  left: someVariable1,
  top: someVariable2
})

// FEtypes[1].left = someVariable1;
// FEtypes[1].top = someVariable2;
```